# vscode is not working properly after introduction of remote WSL feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I disable or uninstall Remote WSL plugin on VScode cursor starts jumping from one place to another. what should i do to avoid this from happening. I don't want to use the plugin.

[image: SNAP]

I have installed WSL so VScode always prompts to install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple code formatter that's why this was happening. remote WSL has nothing to with this problem. sorry for wrong question.